# Java BigDecimal Rounding

Tags: java, rounding, bigdecimal

I am learning BigDecimal and i want it to retrieve the exact number i entered, the following code is rouding the number and i dont know why

```
public static BigDecimal parseFromNumberString(String numberString) {

    if (numberString != null) {

        String nonSpacedString =
            numberString.replaceAll("[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]", "").replaceAll("%", "");

        int indexOfComma = nonSpacedString.indexOf(',');
        int indexOfDot = nonSpacedString.indexOf('.');
        NumberFormat format = null;

        if (indexOfComma < indexOfDot) {
            nonSpacedString = nonSpacedString.replaceAll("[,]", "");
            format = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
        } else if (indexOfComma > indexOfDot) {
            nonSpacedString = nonSpacedString.replaceAll("[.]", "");    
            DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
            otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
            format = new DecimalFormat("##,#", otherSymbols);
        } else {
            format = new DecimalFormat();
        }
        try {
            return new BigDecimal(format.parse(nonSpacedString).doubleValue(), new MathContext(12));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // unrecognized number format
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If i do something like

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BigDecimal d = Test.parseFromNumberString("0.39");
    System.out.println(d);  
}
```

The value printed is 0,00 and not 0.39

Comment: I get `0.39000000`...

Comment: i just ran your code and i get. `0.390000000000` maybe you forgot to save?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
public static BigDecimal parseFromNumberString(String numberString) {

    if (numberString != null) {

        String nonSpacedString =
            numberString.replaceAll("[ \\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r]", "").replaceAll("%", "");

        int indexOfComma = nonSpacedString.indexOf(',');
        int indexOfDot = nonSpacedString.indexOf('.');
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat();
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        String pattern = "#0.0#";           

        if (indexOfComma < indexOfDot) {
            symbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
        } else if (indexOfComma > indexOfDot) {
            symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        } 

        try {
            decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
            decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
            BigDecimal toRet = (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse(nonSpacedString);
            return toRet.setScale(12);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    BigDecimal d = Test.parseFromNumberString("0,39");
    System.out.println(d);  
}
```

Is that what you want??

Answer (score 0):

i just ran your code and i get. `0.390000000000` maybe you forgot to save?

try cleanning your project, restart your ide and recompile. the code should work fine

Comment: I only get that if i run 0,39. If i run 0.39 the number get rounded